# WARNS when a new version of Python is installed via pyenv

Tags: pyenv

I was just exploring pyenv. I already have a base anaconda3 running which has a ton of packages(not a great practice but unfortunate :-P).

When I installed python version 3.11.3 via pyenv `pyenv install 3.11.3` I got a whole bunch of compilation WARNS on failed compilation(imports failing) due to missing packages. Just curious to know the reasons.. maybe that'll help me better understand how pyenv works behind the scene.

TIA

```
WARNING: The Python sqlite3 extension was not compiled. Missing the SQLite3 lib?
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/tkinter/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
WARNING: The Python tkinter extension was not compiled and GUI subsystem has been    detected. Missing the Tk toolkit?
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/lzma.py", line 27, in <module>
from _lzma import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_lzma'
WARNING: The Python lzma extension was not compiled. Missing the lzma lib?
Installed Python-3.11.3 to /home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3
(base) user@workstation:~/.pyenv/versions$ pyenv versions
* system (set by /home/user.pyenv/version)
 3.11.3
 anaconda3-2023.03
```